# Baking more than 1 cut of meat at same time?

Tags: baking

I am cooking 4 stuffed pork loins on the same rack in a 350 degree oven. Cooking time in recipe is 90 min. (Based on 1 meat portion) Does cooking time change for 4 ?

Comment: Different meat, similar scenario: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/63806/oven-temperature-for-multiple-ducks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's best to do a bit of searching through the sites before asking a question, e.g. the answer referenced above should tell you what you need to know. But, keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, unless they are lying so close to each other that they are touching. That would lead to a longer cooking time.